# Select method, changes default ordering of DataTable

Tags: .net, linq

When I convert `DataTable` to `IEnumerable` using `Select` method, default ordering from `sp` is changed! Is any option can I set to prevent this?

```
var list = dataTable.Select();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Just instead of

```
dataTable.Select();
```

I should use

```
dataTable.AsEnumerable();
```